# How do I make a DataGridView invisble when I press a button?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Button and a DataGridView. When I press the button I want the DataGridview to be visible and when I press it again be invisible

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim buttonId As New Button
    Dim dvg As New DataGridView
    Try
        dvg = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        dvg.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

I know the question might sound very basic, but I am quite inexperienced, so the help will be very much appreciated

Comment: The sender in this case is the button not the dgv. `TheDGV.Visible = Not TheDGV.Visible`

Answer (score 1):

first off, i would have the datagridview object as a member of your class.
then i would turn it on and off like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If dgv.Visible Then
        dgv.Hide()
    Else
        dgv.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

hope this helps

Comment: The problem is I dont have the name of the datagridview because it is suppose to be added dynamically. 


In the code that I am working on (not the posted) I have one button for each datagridview and when ever I press the button the datagridview is suppose to show.

Comment: Do you mean that the button is supposed to add the datagridview dynamically, or that the button & datagridview are dynamically created together as a pair?

Comment: They are created together but only when the button is pushed the gridview is suppose to show.

Comment: I have now used the the tag on the button to reference the gridview. But thank you for trying to help me. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Not sure adding controls dynamically is a good idea, but...

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Try
        Dim dgv As New DataGridView
        dgv.Name = "dgvN"
        dgv.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width - 20, 300)
        dgv.Top = Me.ClientSize.Height / 2 - dgv.Height / 2
        dgv.Left = Me.ClientSize.Width / 2 - dgv.Width / 2
        dgv1.BringToFront()
        Me.Controls.Add(dgv)  ' use Controls() of desired container

        Dim newButton As New Button
        newButton.Text = "DGV On/Off"
        newButton.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(newButton.Text, newButton.Font).Width + 20
        newButton.Tag = "dgvN"
        Me.Controls.Add(newButton)  ' use Controls() of desired container

        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf DGVVisibleButtonClick

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Sub DGVVisibleButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.Controls(sender.tag)
    dgv.Visible = Not dgv.Visible
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I could use the tag on the button and thereby  reference the data grid view. I didn't know that there was a tag that could be used that way, so I'm very glad you showed me.

Comment: Yup - you can stuff most types into Tag including Classes. A common bug is to store a reference and have the pointed to object not being exactly what you had in mind. Check out this answer for a variation on hiding the grid - slide it off the edge. BTW you should indicate you have an answer when you have solved the problem.